# Python requests timestamp format "timestamp": "1642696349592", what format is this timestamp?

Tags: python, python-requests, timestamp

Hello in requests i have a json payload with a timestamp but i cant find out what the timestamp format is, so i don't know how to anwser this request/ make it work.

SO can somebody tell me what the "timestamp" format is?
Here is the json payload:

```
                json = {
                    "pageApiId": "200641",
                    "clientDetails": [],
                    "country": "US",
                    "userAction": "",
                    "source": "PageView",
                    "clientTelemetryData": {
                        "category": "PageView",
                        "pageName": "200641",
                        "eventInfo": {
                        "timestamp": "1642696349592",
                        "enforcementSessionToken": "null",
                        "appVersion": "null",
                        "networkType": "null"
                        }
                    },
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in milliseconds. That value corresponds with, roughly, now.

You can create a `datetime.datetime` object from it using [`fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime%20fromtimestamp#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

datetime.fromtimestamp(1642696349592 / 1_000)
#=> datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 20, 11, 32, 29, 592000)
```

Note that the result of the above will be dependent on the machine running this code:

> If optional argument *tz* is `None` or not specified, the timestamp is converted to the platform’s local date and time, and the returned [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime%20fromtimestamp#datetime.datetime) object is naive.

You might want to use [`utcfromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime%20fromtimestamp#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) instead, or pass a time zone to `fromtimestamp()`.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a unix timestamp in milliseconds. You can convert that to a human-readable timestamp like
`datetime.fromtimestamp(1642696349.592)` So basically divide it by 1000 to get seconds.